# How can I visually represent the concept of "planning"?

Tags: symbolism

Trying to create a logo. The customer provides assistance to homeless people by giving them resources and access to providers for help. The word planning is in their name.

Comment: I don't think the concept of "planning" is the correct angle of attack. Consider: "partnership," "uplifting," "empowering"

Comment: @horatio is right. You should also try to identify to whom this logo is targeted. I would not think "planning" is a top priority with homeless people. More so inmediate solutions that might eventually enable them the luxury of planing.

Comment: "Planning" isn't as good from a donor/fundraising angle either.

Comment: @horatio and @leugim make excellent points here.

Answer (score 1):

Flowcharts, architectural, and drafting diagrams all speak to planning.

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments. Discussion helps. This non-profit doesnt have fundraising or take donations. They don't help the homeless directly, they manage the homeless providers. They do point them in the right direction when they are contacted directly. I was trying to stay away from the homeless angle so that I didnt use a house as an image. Seems too obvious.